# Why can I unlock a volume from the terminal but not the unlock prompt?

Tags: macos, password, diskutil, disk-volume

When I try to mount an encrypted image from Finder, it pops up with a password prompt. I am unable to unlock it using that for some reason.

It's not that I don't have the password because I can unlock it using

```
diskutil apfs unlockVolume diskXsY
```

I think it could be something to do with the user being wrong but I'm not sure.

For what it's worth this is what it lists under users:

```
Cryptographic user for diskXsY (1 found)
|
+-- AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA
    Type: Disk User
```

How can I fix the volume so that the prompt works too?